# I have inserted a searchBar in my app, i want to fix the position of my searchbar

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

i want to fix the position of searchbar on the top. i used css position:fixed;. but it does not work.

here is my HTML code:

```
<ion-content padding>
  <ion-searchbar (ionInput)="getItems($event)" style="width:400px; float:right; position:fixed; z-index: 99999;" ></ion-searchbar>
</ion-content>
```

[image]

Please advise

Comment: where you want to put the searchbar? What is the exact issue?

Comment: this is my  'mytask' page. on the top, i have inserted a search bar. and there is a filtered list beneath searchbar which i can scroll but when i scrolls down , the searchbar goes up. how can i fix the position when i scroll the page.

Comment: For handling this you can put the list beneath the search bar in an <ion-scroll> that way search bar will stay in the top and only the task list will scroll.

Comment: <ion-scroll scrollX="true" scrollY="true">
</ion-scroll>       and i have to set height??

Comment: Yes you need to set the ion scroll height, you can specify height in % if required.

Comment: If your search bar scrolls with the content, probably the native scroll is not enabled. In this case, you could try to add the attribute overflow-scroll = true to the ion-content to enable the native scroll.